# JavaScript node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

i made a simple Node.js server that listen on port '8888'. When I run my server and I enter localhost:8888 in my browser (from my computer) i saw the server output.
What URL I need to enter my website from ether computer?.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The server is running on `localhost`. This means it's running as an instance on your local machine. You can't access this from another computer.

Unless.

You are on the same LAN. In that case you can use port forwarding through your router and type in the computer `IP` along with a port that corresponds with your server.

For example:

```
http://computerip:serverport
```

Comment: Can i replace the IP with my computer host name?

Answer (score 0):

> What URL I need to enter my website from ether computer?

Other computers on your local network will typically be able to use the hostname of the machine on which you're running that server. So for instance, if the hostname of the machine is `server123`, you'd use `http://server123:8888` from another machine in the same local network.

That will not typically be possible from *outside* your local network, but of course, if this is on a web host of some kind, they'll have made it possible for that machine to be reached from the 'net. That will involve either an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6), and *may* involve a hostname + domain name such as `http://server123.my-hosting-company.com:8888`. (And you can get your own domain instead and get that set up to point to your hosted server as well.) For details, talk with your hosting company.

Comment: Thank you very much its very help . I have a free hosing account on hostinger if i upload my program to my free domain(michael69.esy.es) than everyone can see it on michael69.esy.es:8888